# How do I get a character from a Unicode value?

Tags: rust

Coming from a JavaScript background, the following code would generate a list of chars one after the other, starting with `0x30A0`:

```
for i = 1 to 9
   String.fromCharCode(0x30A0 + i)
```

chars like ァ etc.

How do I achieve this in Rust?

Comment: You literally just want a sequence of characters without caring for what they are, just that they are in some sort of order?

Comment: @Shepmaster Actually, I want them to start with 0x30A0. Have to edit the question

Comment: `(1..9).map(|i| char::from_u32(0x30A0 + i).unwrap())`

Comment: @Shepmaster got it, thanks!

Comment: _"Coming from a JavaScript background,"_ the code below is not valid JavaScript code however. One might as well just say it is just pseudo-code.